# Rails distinct query with where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have used the following code to show distinct user counts on a view:

```
<%= @miniature.collections.where(status: 'Got').count(:user_id, distinct: true) %> users have this
```

I'm then trying to list out those distinct users but can't work out how to combine the `(:user_id, distinct: true)` into this query:

```
<% @miniature.collections.where(status: 'Got').each do |collection| %>
        <tr><td><%= link_to collection.user.name, collection.user %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

I just can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @immaculate.pine I worked out a way of doing this using `.uniq` rather than `(:user_id, distinct: true)`

In the controller I have

```
@miniature = Miniature.find(params[:miniature_id])
@usergot = User.joins(:collections).where(collections: {status: 'Got', miniature: @miniature}).uniq
@userwant = User.joins(:collections).where(collections: {status: 'Want', miniature: @miniature}).uniq
```

Then for the count I just call

```
<%= @usergot.count %>
 users have this
```

or indeed

```
<%= @userwant.count %>
         users want this
```

and for the list it's

```
<% @usergot.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= link_to user.name, user %></td></tr>
      <% end %>
```

Works perfect and not too ugly.

Comment: Oops, I thought that you want to find both 'Got' and 'Want' miniatures from the description. And yes, I forgot about the uniqueness. Glad that I helped you to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all users that have miniatures with 'Got' status then it's better to start from another side.

Controller:

```
@miniature = Miniature.find(...)
@users = User.joins(:collections).where(collections: {status: 'Got', miniature: @miniature})
```

View:

```
<%= @users.count %> users have this
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr><td><%= link_to user.name, user %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sounds good. The thing is, I want to be able to do this on the same page with both status: 'Got' and :status 'Want', and this way would limit me to just one right?

Comment: You can change the condition to `status: ['Got', 'Want']`. The resulting query is `@users = User.joins(:collections).where(collections: {status: ['Got', 'Want'], miniature: @miniature})`.

Comment: I can't see how that solves the problem I'm afraid. This just returns a mixed Got and Want list and loses the distinct. I've got that bit working now by defining usergot and userwant but then I can't get that working at all in the following list. I want to get lists of the distinct users with Got and Want status collections, of which they may have many. I'll keep at it.